# Delete last 3 lines within while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null) but not open a new text file to delete the lines?

Tags: c#

This is the code I've seen so far to delete last 3 lines in a text file, but it's required to determine string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(); which is nt necessary for me to do so.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users.txt");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int count = lines.Length - 3; // except last 3 lines 
            for (int s = 0; s < count; s++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(lines[s]);

            }
```

The code works well, but I don't wanna re-read the file as I've mentioned the streamreader above :

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users.txt"))
```

Im new to C#, as far as I know, after using streamreader, and if I wanna modify the lines, I have to use this :

```
while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
{
#sample codes inside the bracket
                    line = line.Replace("|", "");
                    line = line.Replace("MY30", "");
                    line = line.Replace("E", "");
}
```

So, is there any way to delete the last 3 lines in the file within the "while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)" ??

I have to delete lines, replace lines and a few more modications in one shot, so I can't keep opening/reading the same text file again and again to modify the lines. I hope the way I ask is understable for you guys >.<

Plz help me, I know the question sounds simple but I've searched so many ways to solve it but failed =(

So far, my code is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
public class Read
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\SAP Report.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWrite (@"C:\\Users\output2.txt"))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    line = line.Replace("|", "");
                    line = line.Replace("MY30", "");
                    line = line.Replace("E", "");

                    line = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line, @"\s{2,}", " ");

                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
     }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my next task is to delete the last 3 lines in the file after these codes, and I need help on this one.

Thank you.

Comment: How big is your file anyway?  ReadAllLines() is expensive for very big files (> 100 MB) but are you in that category?

Comment: Its nt a big file, jz a normal text file =)

Answer (score 3):

With **File.ReadAllLines** you have already read the file, so you can process each one line in the **string[]** (replaces and regexes), and then write them in the output. You don't have to reread them and put them in the **StringBuilder**.

Comment: Is there any examples for your reply? Im stil new to C#.
Thank u =)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a "rolling window" of the previous three lines:

```
string[] previousLines = new string[3];
int index = 0;
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (previousLines[index] != null)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(previousLines[index]);
    }
    line = line.Replace("|", "")
               .Replace("MY30", "")
               .Replace("E", "");
    line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s{2,}", " ");
    previousLines[index] = line;
    index = (index + 1) % previousLines.Length;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it workds =D But i dun understand
    previousLines[index] = line;     
    index = (index + 1) % previousLines.Length;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending the lines directly to the string builder, you could keep a list of the lines and join them later on. That way you can easily leave out the last three lines.

To reduce the amount lines you have to keep in the list, you could regularly append one line of the list and remove it from it. So you would keep a buffer of 3 lines in an array and would pop & append a line whenever the buffer contains 4 lines.